# ESP32 - Can I safely use GPIO ADC2 pins for non-adc use while using WiFi

Tags: gpio, esp32

According to ESP32 design guidelines; ADC2 GPIO's should not be used when using WiFi due to conflicts. (or used with restrictions)

This affects GPIOs 2,12-15 and 25-27.

Suppose I use don't use any of the ADC2 GPIOs for analogReads while using WiFi, can I safely use those ADC2 GPIO pins for digitalWrites and digitalReads without conflict to WiFi?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are still available to the other function of the pins, they just can't be internally connected to the ADC2 module and used for analog to digital conversions.

The Wifi usage of ADC2 is done internally on the chip and is not routed through the pins.

Some official development board do use some of these specific pins for other purposes (like auto programming circuits, etc) so may be unavailable for other reasons.